# Blender, using compositing for light sources

Tags: blender

I am in the blender compositing panel and i was using cycles at the time and i found my self making blurs and glares for lights in my scene, however what if i wanted to make two differant emmision objects but have one with differant properties than the other, because i found that when you use compositing it effects the entire image in the mask. i have tried moving too differant layers... but nothing worked. i dont know but masks might work... i havnt tried masks yet.

if any of that made any sense, any opinions would be amazing

thanks -Adam

the most recent update for blender was used "2.78"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://blender.stackexchange.com.